# Can the magic which resides in objects be put into spells?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, magical-theory, spells

Can a person create a spell which has the same effect as a magical object? For instance, could a wizard create a spell that, like the Mirror of Erised, shows the caster (or his target) that which they truly want?

Comment: They had to enchant the item with that Magic in the first place.

Comment: @cde not all of them have to be castable spells, do they? Couldn't some be results from objects being inserted in some potions, or just simply a magic that isn't initially castable, or a result of multiple spells at once? Afterwardss, however, would they be able to "take it" from the object and turn it into a spell?

Comment: Also, if it's an unknown sort of magic, maybe from a different culture or origin, could a wizard "reverse-engineer" it out of the object?

Comment: Your initial question is different. Can someone copy an items effect is different than reverse engineering and recreating the same magic. You should reword this and/or maybe create an additional question.

Comment: Could you have two different kinds of magic with the exact same result? And when I say reverse engineer I do mean into a spell. Maybe I phrased my last comment wrong. I meant that if you didn't know the magical origin of the artifact, you'd still be able to know how it worked (not what it does, but how it does it) and turn that into a spell. So, f.i., I don't know what is actually behind the mirror of erised, but am I able to fully reproduce it's powers into the form of a spell?

Comment: Look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magical_objects_in_Harry_Potter the DA coins and the cloaks seem to answer this

Answer (score 2):

A person can use a spell with the same effect as a magical object; as shown with the explanation of invisibility cloaks in book 7. The cloaks can be made from demiguise hair, which would be a naturally occurring magical object. A spell can be used for the same thing, by casting a bedazzling hex or disillusionment charm on a regular cloak. A spell could also be used to cast a disillusionment charm on a person.

Effect replication might not be possible with all magical objects. Wands for one seem to be in a class of their own. I can think of no evidence in the books of someone creating or possessing something or using a spell that does a wand's job but isn't a wand. I also know of no evidence that wands can be created by any means other than by fashioning naturally occurring magical objects into a wand.

Your question also seems to ask about inventiveness in spell-making. There are numerous mentions of both Dumbledore & Voldemort advancing the study of magic. It is entirely plausible that a powerful & inventive witch or wizard would seek to create a new spell based on the witnessed effect of a magical object. However, like with levicorpus, it would be difficult (maybe impossible) to know if it was a new invention or a rediscovery.

Answer (score 1):

> For instance, could a wizard create a spell that, like the Mirror of Erised, shows the caster (or his target) that which they truly want?

Presumably, yes, but they would likely have cast it upon some reflecting or otherwise visual surface, like a mirror, water, or a tv screen. How else would the person see that which they most desired? I do suspect that item is probably unique.

Would it be permanent? It appears that only great wizards are able to make permanent magical items. Otherwise they seem to fade over time, like the Potter Stinks badges, or the invisibility cloaks that Ron talks about (how they become tattered and more visible over time).

Could it be reverse engineered? Presumably yes. You make note of all the properties of the said magical item, and you then construct spells to duplicate the behavior.

You could probably cast the Remembral enchantment on anything (maybe even yourself) and it would become red when you forgot something. The ball which contains the permanent enchantment is simply what has become the standard delivery for that spell.

Comment: **You could probably cast the Remembral enchantment on anything (maybe even yourself)** I can just imagine how embarrassed some might look when they turn red at the worst possible times...Another example of permanent: Hermione's DA coins.